# how to consume http post in elm with header and body

Tags: elm

I am new in elm and try to consume web api using http post request with header and body using 0.17.1 version but did not get any documentation.

So any one help me to implement this functionality

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/rgrempel/elm-web-api). Older doc, but you should have a start with it

Comment: @lokusking I have web api url i.e http://xyz/method and i am using evancz/elm-http package using http.post but don't get any idea about how to send body and header with this http post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [send](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http#send) method of the Http package gives you the possibility to create and send a custom request. For example, a post request could be something like

```
postRequest : Request
postRequest =
    { verb = "POST"
    , headers =
        [ ("Origin", "http://elm-lang.org")
        , ("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST")
        , ("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Custom-Header")
        ]
    , url = "http://example.com/hats"
    , body = empty
    }
```

You can then create the `Task` that represent the request using the `send` function like

```
send defaultSettings postRequest
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i have implemented the same `postRequest : Http.Request
postRequest =
    { verb = "POST"
    , headers =
        [ ("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ]
    , url = "http://mywebapi/events/list"
    , body = Http.string """{ "domainId": 1 }"""
    }

getEventList : Task.Task Http.RawError Http.Response
getEventList = 
       Http.send Http.defaultSettings postRequest`  but i will get the response

Comment: How i will get response from service and update the model?

Comment: @ManuChawla you'd better read a bit about how to use tasks. This is a good starting point: http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/http.html